# Two NICs and a PC

Tags: networking, network-adapter

I'm trying to place a PC between a key vault device and a network. The idea is, the computer has PC that communicates with the device, and the device reports back, logging info (key pulls/returns) into a database on the PC.

I can access the software on the PC, so I can generate reports. However, the PC cannot access the key vault device.

I have configured two NICs on the PC, both with static IPs. (I need a static to talk to the device. I want a static on the network side for ease in communicating with the software on the PC.)

Here's a rough picture, with IP addresses:

Key Vault (192.168.40.97) <--  Crossover cable -->NIC2 (192.168.40.100) -----PC----- NIC1 (192.168.40.152)<-- Network -->

When I ping the vault from the PC, I get this message:
"Reply from 192.168.40.152: Destination host unreachable."

What do I need to do to get the PC and the key vault to communicate? Some kind of routing table?

Comment: You've made things hard on yourself unnecessarily by using such similar IP addresses for two different networks. Why not number the vault 192.168.41.1 and NIC2 192.168.41.2?

Comment: Your rough picture needs to include /prefixlen or subnet mask of every interface.

Comment: Also, the vault should never attempt to ping or access 192.168.40.152 in any way. That's the PC's address on a network the vault is not supposed to have access to, right? So the vault is not supposed to be able to reach it. Use 192.168.40.100 when talking to the vault since that's the PC's address on the network the vault is supposed to access. (See how the similar addresses leads to confusion?)

Comment: When the PC tries to access the vault, how are you expecting it to know that it needs to use NIC2 to reach it and not NIC1?

Comment: Put the key server/device adn the second NIC on a different subnet

Answer (score 0):

You said it yourself, partially: "some sort of routing table". But an easier and simpler sollution would be to use a different logical network. For example, if your internet gateway is on `192.168.40.0/24` you could place the key vault on `192.168.41.0/24`. This way, both of your NICs won't reside on the same network from an addressing perspective, and it's easier for the routing algorithm to figure out which card to use for which address.

If you insist on using the `192.168.40.x` range, you could subnet it further by using a `/25` address (also known as `255.255.255.128` subnet mask). If you do this `192.168.40.1-127` will not be on the same logical network as `192.168.129-254`, and you can select IPs accordingly. You could also subnet it by using an even tighter mask, so that the IP's you use today are separated in the same way.